# How to set values for SSIS parameters

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I am trying to execute a SSIS package through managed code and I would like to set the value of parameters in the package:

```
PackageInfo ssisPackage = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["SWIS5_PersonImport"].Projects["SWIS5_PersonImport"].Packages["EducatorsUploader.dtsx"];
ssisPackage.Parameters["FlatFile_Path"].Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, parameter.FilePath);
```

The code above shows how I have tried and it does not work, I have found documentation from previews versions where the package had a collection of variables, but I have not been able to find said collection, so does anyone have any ideas on how to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: "Does not work". Does it not appear to apply the variables or does it throw an error?

Comment: It appear to apply the variables.

Comment: Same problem here - did you get it working?

Comment: I ended up going in a different path, to achieve the same, but unfortunately, I don't recall what it was, and no longer have access to the code. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If it is a package parameter you need to set values this way:

```
Dim setValueParameters As New ObjectModel.Collection(Of PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet)
Dim exp As New PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
                exp.ObjectType = 30
                exp.ParameterName = sp.Name
                If sp.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    Select Case sp.TypeCode
                        Case TypeCode.String
                            exp.ParameterValue = sp.Value
                        Case Else
                            exp.ParameterValue = Convert.ChangeType(sp.Value, sp.TypeCode)
                    End Select
                End If

                setValueParameters.Add(exp)

package.Execute(use32BitRuntime, nothing, setValueParameters
```